# Node scaling with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a plot upon which I would like to have several nodes. The node is correctly located. I was able to using the `minimum size` option rescale it to larger sizes (such as 1 or 2 cm).
However, going below the 0.1 cm range does not rescale the node. In my case I wish to make the node exactly 0.0051 cm. Am I going about this the wrong way? How do I rescale the node and make it smaller?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:1.8, xscale = 6, yscale = 1.5]

\draw[->]  (-0.2,0)  --  (2,0)  node[right]  {$x$};
\draw[->]  (0,-1.2)  --  (0,4)  node[above]  {$f(x)$};

\draw[color=blue]      plot  (\x,{\x^2+1})        node[right]  {};
\node(1) at (0.5,0) [circle,draw, fill, minimum size = 0.0051cm]{};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

**EDIT**

Following @cfr and @marmot 's comments it seems that this is an incorrect approach. I am making very small objects and scaling them up, which increases likelihood of `dimension too large` errors later on, when I reach the limits of the `tikz` package.

I think it is appropriate here to change the nature of the question. How can I recode the above such that I am *not* making very small objects and scaling them up? I would like to get an exact replica of the plot but with different code.

Thanks

Comment: `minimum size` is, as its name suggests, a minimum size. You can scale nodes down with `scale=...` but in your case it might be simpler to draw a filled circle instead of a node: `\fill (0.5,0) circle(0.0051cm)` and then perhaps to add `\coordinate (1) at (0.5,0);`. (I am also not sure if you really want to draw such a small object, it is not visible on the line anyway, so the coordinate alone may do.)

Comment: I don't want to draw a small object. I want to control the size of every object in my drawing, including nodes. In this case scale worked. Thanks

Comment: You can do that, of course, but may sooner or later run into `dimension too large` errors.

Comment: This is why it's a bad idea to make things very small and then scale them up. Here, you're scaling by a factor of 1.5 in one direction and a factor of 6 in the other, but creating tiny objects initially to scale up. You are less likely to encounter `dimension too large` errors, if you avoid dealing with smaller (or larger) dimensions than you need to.) Empty nodes like this are a bit pointless anyway, as @marmot suggests. I.e. not that you can't *try* to do as you want, but you'll encounter the limits sooner. Also, you'll get less accurate dimensions, as you're reducing precision.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect your comments. In this case what I would like to ask is how to recode the above such that I get an equivalent  `tikzpicture` with perhaps different code that isn't rescaling tiny objects up?

Comment: I guess you may want to be even clearer than that. Why do you want to draw the circle as a node? And given that `xscale` and `yscale` differ, do you want to have a circle or an ellipse in the end? (And also: what is `node[right]  {}` good for?)

Comment: `node[right]{}` is not good for anything, I have removed it. I want to have a circle, definitely not an ellipse, at the end. I want to draw it as a node because in practical terms, thats what it is. It's supposed to indicate a point on a plot. As a node I think it will also be easier to reference if I want to draw paths going from it to other nodes in the drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `inner sep=0pt` you remove the space TikZ add to the node dimension to separate the text from the border (even if the node has no text, as in your case).

After that, `minimum size` is the actual minimum size of the node, and you can have your node as small as you like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:1.8, xscale = 6, yscale = 1.5]

\draw[->]  (-0.2,0)  --  (2,0)  node[right]  {$x$};
\draw[->]  (0,-1.2)  --  (0,4)  node[above]  {$f(x)$};

\draw[color=blue]      plot  (\x,{\x^2+1})        node[right]  {};
\node(1) at (0.5,0) [circle,draw, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum size = 0.05cm]{};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: solid. Thanks for your help. So it can be a node contrarily to what was said in the comments.

Comment: @user32882 You're welcome. Sincerely, I didn't read the comments :)

Comment: They were trying to make me think that there was no point drawing it as a node :P, that a circle was the way to go...

Comment: @user32882 It's strange bacause marmot and cfr are TikZ experts, perhaps they misunderstood the question...

Comment: I don't doubt it. Perhaps my question was initially not very clear. I felt that  `tikz` should be able to handle nodes of any size, which is why I insisted on it being a node. In any case thanks to everyone for taking the time to look at this question

Comment: @user32882 You're welcome and thank you for accepting my answer! Don't hesitate to ask other questions if you need help!